# How to deploy an ASP.NET 5 Aurelia app to Azure from VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, aurelia, jspm, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy an [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) application based on [the ASP.NET 5 ES2016 navigation skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-es2016-asp.net5) to Microsoft Azure using Web Deploy (*[right-click] -> publish*) from within Visual Studio 2015.

But I can't get the depolyment to work.

I've changed the `prepublish` settings in the `project.json` file to:

```
"prepublish": [ "npm install", "gulp bundle" ]
```

but this only makes the Publish process fail within Visual Studio. Running `gulp bundle` from the console works fine.

So my next attempt has been to remove all `prepublish` tasks, run `gulp bundle` manually and then publish. This allows the publish process to complete, but the web application on azure never loads and end up giving me a timeout.

Thinking that it might have something to do with the `jspm_packages` folder I've tried including those in the `Web.xproj` file based on [this github thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/468#issuecomment-142798678), but this results in the following error:

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
```

### Update

I've tried setting the `prepublish` scripts back and running `dnu publish` from the console. That runs without a problem ad generates all the necessary output in the `\bin\output\wwwroot` folder. This same process fail however when run from the Publish contect-menu action in Visual Studio; no output is generated.

Just adding it here in case it sheds some light into the issue.

### Update 2

Ok, I noticed that the `dnu publish` command's closing message is

```
Using command 'web' as entry point for web.config
```

And then a penny dropped. The Aurelia Skeleton Navigation solution defines the following command in `project.json:

```
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://*:9000/",
```

which of course will not work in Azure. So, I removed the `--server.urls` options, removed `prepublish` scripts again form the `project.json` and lo and behold, the app runs...

<s>...unbundled.</s>

Anyhow, a lot has changed since starting to type this question, but I am still wondering:

1. Why does publishing fail from Visual Studio when I have `prepublish` tasks defined?
2. <s>Most importantly, how can I publish a bundled Aurelia app to azure?</s>

### Update 3

The bundling works when runt from the console apparently. I think I never tried publishing the bundled app after removing the `--server.urls` setting from `project.json`.

#### So where are we at?

Publishing to Azure with `"prepublish": [ "gulp bundle" ]` still fails. This is the `gulpfile.js`  that comes with the Aurelia Navigation Skeleton:

```
require('require-dir')('build/tasks');
```

And Visual Studio throws an error on the following line of `watch.js` when running `prepublish` tasks:

```
console.log(`File ${event.path} was ${event.type}, running tasks...`);
```

Which is quite incomprehensible because the `bundle`  task ***does not*** call `watch`. Ever. And running `gulp bundle` from the console works as expected.

So it looks like VS2015 is *loading every task from the `build/tasks` folder*. 
I've tried commenting out the `watch.js`  file completely, but then I only the the following error: `prepublish failed with code 1`.

Any help or ideas on why I can't Publish with `prepublish` tasks would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the typescript or ECMA skeleton?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that: I'm using ES2106. I've updated my question to reflect it.

Comment: show you web.config file after you published your app

Comment: Have you been able to publish locally to IIS?

Comment: @Pawel, that's the thing, when trying to publish from Visual Studio, there is no config afterwards; the process never finishes.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I've managed to publish to azure without bundling and without the `prepublish` tasks; I have to run the gulp tasks manually before publishing

Comment: That's good to know. Are you wanting to know how to automate the gulp tasks?

Comment: Is there an error message in output when you include the gulp task in your project.json?

Comment: @BlakeMumford, sorry it took a while to reply. I've updated my question (`Update 3`) to reflect where I stand at the moment.

Comment: @SergiPapaseit Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @AndreSantos nope :(

Answer (score 1):

To publish the [Aurelia ASP.NET 5 ES2016 navigation skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/a90a01370611d40fb0a36634af81239baef965ac/skeleton-es2016-asp.net5/src/skeleton-navigation-es2016-vs) to Azure with Web Deploy (Right-click > publish), we must make two changes to project.json.

Add a prepublish entry that will install NPM dependencies (otherwise gulp with fail), install JSPM packages, and bundle with gulp.

```
"prepublish": [ "npm install", "jspm install -y", "gulp bundle" ]
```

Delete `--server.urls=http://*:9000/` from the web command, because that address is not supported in Azure. This is the correct entry:

```
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
```

With those two changes, Web Deploy is working to both local IIS and to an Azure Web App using Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 2.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. We've actually managed to set up deployment with AppVeyor, which is definitely the way to go, but this question needs closure :)